# Table 'roles_users' is already defined for this MetaData instance

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get a current_user information in my views and I include from `users.models import *`

Then in my code return current_user;

```
@app.route('/panel')
@login_required
def access_panel():
    return current_user.email;
```

Once I run my server it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 6, in <module>
    from nadel import app
  File "/Users/tbd/Desktop/Projects/nadel/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from users import views
  File "/Users/tbd/Desktop/Projects/nadel/users/views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from users.models import *
  File "/Users/tbd/Desktop/Projects/nadel/users/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id')))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 67, in _make_table
    return sqlalchemy.Table(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 398, in __new__
    "existing Table object." % key)
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'roles_users' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.
```

In my model I have:

```
from nadel import db
from flask.ext.security import UserMixin, RoleMixin

# Define models
roles_users = db.Table('roles_users',
        db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
        db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id')))

class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    #confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    last_login_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    current_login_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    last_login_ip = db.Column(db.String(32))
    current_login_ip = db.Column(db.String(32))
    login_count = db.Column(db.Integer)

    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error and how to solve it.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue under a test environment using py3 while running doctests, the same error raises when pytest starts collecting files. I found that this error might be related to py3 envs with the latest changes introduced in the current version of flask-sqlalchemy library. I've no issues while running in py2.7, but it isn't a choice for me, so I moved to plain SQLAlchemy library which solves the issue at all.

Comment: The table already exists in your db, so you could change the setup a bit or just catch a `InvalidRequestError` and in the except  `roles_users = db.metadata.tables["roles_users"]`, or just set  `useexisting=True` in the Table call

Comment: @PadraicCunningham , can you elaborate on your method? I am facing the same problem but still unable to solve it.

Answer (score 50):

I had a similar error. My problem was importing the class that inherits `db.Model` from two different files using a relative import. `Flask-SQLAlchemy` mapped the two imports as two different table definitions and tried to create two tables. I fixed this issue by using the absolute import path in both files.

Comment: Had quite the same problems, I was importing `db.Model` once relatively, once absolutely.

Comment: yes, this was happening to me because i was moving some code around... IDE helpfully put one import at src.db.models, and another at src.db.models (so my models were being imported twice, separately)

Comment: worked also for me

Comment: This answer was the source of my issue as well (varying import paths for the same model amongst tests). Adding `__table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}` fixes the issue at the ORM level, but not in ones code. I think should be a last effort.

Comment: I forgot i moved some files around my project and that was exactly the reason why i got this error. good answer!

Comment: In my case PyCharm added relative paths instead of absolute ones. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: If you happen to be working with SQLModel in FastAPI the same situation applies. Keep an eye on those imports.

Comment: Why would importing it once relatively, once absolutely cause this, can someone explain the root cause?

Answer (score 37):

Try adding:

> `__table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}`

right below  `__tablename__`

Reference:  [https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html?highlight=**table_args**](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html?highlight=__table_args__)

Comment: will this modify the table in the database or just the table object?

Comment: This solution works, but I'm interested to understand what it actually does.

Comment: This solution might work, but if it does, there's a good chance it's masking other issues - I'd recommend exploring other options before just slapping this on a table class as a band-aid.

Comment: this doesn't resolve the issue. it only makes the error go away. this setting: *indicates that Column objects present in the already-existing Table object should be replaced with columns of the same name retrieved from the autoload process.*

Answer (score 30):

I had this error when I had created a new class by copy-pasting a previous class. It turned out I had forgotten to change the `__tablename__`, so I had two classes with the same `__tablename__` property. This caused the error, and changing the property resolved it.

Comment: That's what did it in my case, too.  It can be sometimes too easy to miss something so simple.

Answer (score 18):

This depends on what you want to do, are you trying to:

1. delete the old class and repalce it with a new class mapping? Or,
2. Keep the old class and just restart your app?

**In the first case using your example above,** try running the following line before defining your classes:

```
db.metadata.clear()
```

The reason is the first time you declare a SQLAlchemy Mapping by defining a python class, the definition of the class is saved to the metadata object, in order to prevent conflicts caused by multiple definitions being mapped to the same table.

When you call the `clear()` method you clear all the table definitions held in memory by the Metadata object, which allows you to declare them again.

**In the second case when you're just restarting the app**
I would write a test to see if the table already exists using the [reflect method](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html):

```
db.metadata.reflect(engine=engine)
```

Where engine is your db connection created using `create_engine()`, and see if your tables already exist and only define the class if the table is undefined.

Comment: Is it also possible to clear only a specific table instead of all tables?

Comment: @JensWagemaker: Remove option lets you do that -  https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.remove

Answer (score 10):

Its one year late but if someone doesn't find the solution in the given answers may be this can solve the problem -

I had this same problem with my class which was inherited from db.Model (of flask_sqlalchemy).

My code looked like this -

```
class MasterDB(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'masterdb'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'schema_any'}
    ...
    ...
```

Resolved it by specifying the ***abstract*** property to True in the class variable list.
Add it in the class variable list like this and it should work -

```
class MasterDB(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'masterdb'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'schema_any'}
    __abstract__ = True
```

Answer (score 10):

My name is Jacob. I had the same situation.

**The issue is this**: this occurs when you are importing parent and child tables in the same code. Then you import CHILD table, the CHILD table brings the parent table's structure also into the metadata. So you don't need to import PARENT table again.

**The solution is this**: you would need to rearrange the order of importing the ORM structures in your code. The order is based on parent + child relation.

**Example**: The following yields an error:

```
import CHILD_ORM
import PARENT_ORM
```

Rearrange the order as follows, to prevent the error:

```
import PARENT_ORM   
import CHILD_ORM
```

Comment: This is the only answer which fixed my problem: I was trying out GINO with Alembic and needed to manually import all my models in the correct order in `migrations/env.py` for it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

TL;DR

- If you encounter this error when trying to register flask blueprint to application, check if Model importing path is consistent across all blueprints where imports the Model

For example

- Blueprint 1: `from A.B.C import Model A`
- Blueprint 2: `from .B.C import Model A` (This raises error, importing path should be consistent across all blueprints that imports the same model. So it should be `from A.B.C import Model A`)

I haven't dig this issue to find out what is the cause, but I guess that SQLAlchemy manages Model with its imported namespace and raise error when different namespace is defined but the models are same.

Answer (score 3):

I am not hundred percent sure, but this issue might be happening due to the fact that the same table is being created from the same module twice. In my situation, I realized I was importing the same module from two different locations *and* `module.__init__` automatically gets executed, which imports the `model.py` **twice**. Therefore causing a metadata conflict, I guess the metadata/namespace is exactly same. I read other answers but none of them clearly explained which choices we do have here.

As far as I looked into the source code, we have two choices:

1. `__table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}`
2. `__table_args__ = {'keep_existing': True}`

First one allows you to extend the table, as the name suggests, but that wouldn't be your preferred choice depending on the situation. I am not sure if that even creates any performance overhead but there is that possibility too.

Second option just keeps the table as it is and does not modify it. In the end the second option was my preferred choice thinking that it's just a simple check if the table exists.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem.
After reading this thread I was able to mange it.
Like user N. Quest in his message from Feb 3, 2019 I forgot to change `__tablename__` and had two classes with same value

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting this error while running the flask app in development mode:

```
FLASK_ENV=development flask run
```

The dynamic reloading feature from flask apparently does reload the metadata instances as you might expect. Restarting the app as suggested by "Spcogg the second" resolves this issue for me!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a bug in imports.

It's just that the `roles_users` model is imported multiple times in one of your components.

This can happen if you imported into several components in which there is already an import of the required model

Examle:

```py
from schemas.user import UserSchema # have `from models.user import User` inside
from blocs.users import UsersBLOC # have `from models.user import User` inside
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I was importing and defining explicitly the models  in foreign key relations (like in the [examples](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many) of the official doc)

Bad:

`ForeignKey(User.id)`

Well (not import model):

`ForeignKey("user.id")`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by deleting that pycache folders as outlined by
CT83

> We faced this exact same bug in production. The code worked fine for
> the developer who wrote it but not for me or in production. This had
> happened once before as well.
>
> Turns out there were older leftover .pyc files in directories which
> were deleted in subsequent commits.
>
> So, basically we hit the union of two problems.
>
> Having left over .pyc files on the disk. Git Ignoring empty
> directories full of files in .gitignore Deleting the directories and
> cleaning the .pyc files solved the problem.
>
> Did not see many answers suggesting this as a fix, so thought I would
> chip in.

Source: https://github.com/pallets-eco/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/672#issuecomment-478195961

Answer (score 0):

I received this error because I forgot to define the primary key in the DB model. This was a classic copy and paste error, because I removed the column with the primary key and did not set it for the relevant column of the "new" table which was a bit different from the original one.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a lot of things causing this error. In my case, I got rid of it by adding `primary_key=True` to my primary key column (which I had forgotten).

Answer (score 0):

So I just had this issue. No matter what I did I could not solve it, even if I set extend_existing. I originally created a new model within the file of another and then moved it to its own file. I think this kinda borked things even though they were named different. So all I did was rename the model class (not the table) it was griping about and then renamed it back and it solved the issue. Import error I guess.

Answer (score -1):

I saw this same error using jupyter notebook.  I was importing sqlalchemy table classes from a library stored on disk and there was a bug in the definition.  After fixing the bug I re-ran the import and saw this error. Simply restarting the jupyter kernel and then rerunning the import resolved the issue.