# SQLAlchemy error when autogenerating documentation for database module using pdoc3

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, autodoc, pdoc

I'm creating documentation for a project using `pydoc3` but am encountering an odd error from `SQLAlchemy` when running against my `database` module.

### Background

**Project layout:**

```
PROJECT_NAME/
|-- __init__.py
|
|-- api
|   |-- main.py
|
|-- database
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- metadata.py
|
|   |-- methods
|       |-- __init__.py
|       |-- foo.py
|
|   |-- models
|       |-- __init__.py
|       |-- base.py
|       |-- models.py
|
| - tests
|   |-- test_this.py
...
```

**Command to generate documentation:**
*Where `MODULE` is the name of the module...*

```sh
python3 venv/bin/pdoc3 --html --output-dir docs $MODULE
```

### The problem:

**I'm able to generate documentation for each module, one at a time with no issues.**
*(Ex: `python3 venv/bin/pdoc3 --html --output-dir docs database`)*

**But when I try generating documentation for the entire project** (`MODULE='.'`), **I get the following error:**

> ImportError: Error importing 'PROJECT_NAME.database':
>
> InvalidRequestError: Table 'FooBar' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.

---

What makes this error odd is that I have a full testing suite where there are no issues at all. Further, the error occurs in `database.__init__.py` which just doesn't make sense to me at all.

---

### As far as a possible solution:

*My thought is that my issue is coming from how I've configured my `declarative base`...*

**Content of `database.__init__.py`:**

```py
from .metadata import metadata
from . import methods
from . import models
```

**Content of `database.metadata.py`:**

```py
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
metadata = MetaData()
```

**Content of `database.models.base.py`:**

```py
from database import metadata
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)
```

**Content of `database.models.model.py`:**

```py
from database.models import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

class FooBar(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'foo_bar'
    __table_args__ = {
        'comment': 'Example...'
    }

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(80), nullable=False, unique=True)
```

Is it possible that my models are attempted to be created twice by pydoc when called from the root?

I'm at a total loss here, not sure what resource to use to investigate further.

---

### Update:

Following [this answer as inspa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37908767/table-roles-users-is-already-defined-for-this-metadata-instance/57789224#57789224), if I update the format of `database.__init__.py`, `pdoc3` is able parse my database module, though, not `database.models` *(which I explicitly escape, because done is better than perfect)*.

**Revised `database.__init__.py`**

```py
__pdoc__ = {'models': False}

from database.metadata import metadata
from database import methods
from database import models
```

Comment: Just the error line does not a full traceback make. Apparently pdoc3 imports `FooBar`'s module another time, and the `declarative_base` doesn't like it. Have you tried `cd .. && pdoc3 whole_project_dir`, with project _named_ rather than dot?

Comment: Interesting suggestion @K3---rnc, let me try that.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve my issue @K3---rnc --> my import paths aren't working with this approach.